# GlassFish application reload with asadmin

Tags: glassfish

Is it possible to reload a web application in GlassFish 4 using the asadmin command line tool?   The GlassFish web console has a "reload" button you can push that does this.  Is there an equivalent for asadmin?   I know there is dynamic reloading where you change a file and it reloads, but I just deployed a war file and now want to reload it so it re-connects to an external socket server (no code has changed and since it was a war I don't think there is a file to touch - further I've disabled dynamic reloading on production server).   If I use use "redeploy" that works too, but you must specify a war file, which is annoying as that means I've got to leave one in a fixed spot and make sure it is in sync with whatever is actually deployed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like asadmin doesn't have a "reload" subcommand (all subcommands listed on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/gihzw.html).

Maybe using the command "asadmin disable {applicationName}" followed by "asadmin enable {applicationName}" will have the same effect, that is probably what glassfish does when you hit reload button.

Comment: You are correct that disable and then enable causes GlassFish to reload the application.   This is better than "redeploy" as it doesn't require you to have a war file laying around that you are confident is the same code already running.

Comment: One issue with this clunky work-around though: you lose all state.   The "redeploy" command has the --keepstate=true argument to maintain user sessions.

Comment: You are right, I'm not sure but I think the reload button won't keep the state eighter, if that is true, "redeploy" may be your best option even if your application is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is execute this `touch .reload` into the glassfish application directory.

```
glassfish4/glassfish/domains/{domain-name}/applications/{application-name}/
```

Comment: I've disabled dynamic reloading in my production environment as indicated in the question so this won't work.  In my development environment I believe Netbeans may be using the .reload trick.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto https://stackoverflow.com/a/31405387/4722577 above here's documentation to the `touch .reload` to reload your app:

[image]

This is from the following Oracle Glassfish doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/pdf/821-2417.pdf